# How to remove childNode item before last childNode using jQuery/Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove the childNode item before the last childNode item.

I currently have a table and I am trying to remove the 2nd last row on the table.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    **I want to remove the row below. thead is the parent node and I want to remove the 2nd last row**
     <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
<thead>
```

Using jQuery, I tried:

```
$('thead').children().last().remove();
```

but this removes the last childNode whereas I want to remove the element before the last element.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/prev. `.children().last().prev().remove()`

Comment: Thank you! Still kind of new to jQuery and I could not find it anywhere on google. I guess I have to google harder.

Comment: or in vanila JS
`var elements = document.querySelectorAll('thead tr'); elements[elements.length - 2].remove();` where `elements.length - 1` is the last element, and you need one before last, so you have to subtract one more `elements.length - 2`

Answer (score 1):

You could do it all with a selector:

```js
$('button').click(function () {
  $('thead > tr:not(:last):last').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><td>row 1<td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 2<td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 3<td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 4<td></tr>
  <thead>
<table>

<button>Do it</button>
```